# How to take an array from user in flutter from text field?

Tags: dart, flutter

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
TextField XnumField = new TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "X array"),
  onSubmitted: (String text){
      for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        X[i] = int.parse(text);
      }
  },
);
```

Comment: What exactly you want achieve ?

Comment: when every i try input the value at index 0 it assigns same value to every index.

Comment: to develop a calculator like stuff?

Comment: yeah something like that

Comment: i am trying to create app for solving different interpolation sums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: demo]

Hi,
If you are looking for something like this here you go.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new DemoScreen(),
  ));
}

class DemoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoScreenState createState() => new _DemoScreenState();
}

class _DemoScreenState extends State<DemoScreen> {
  List<int> _myList = new List();
  TextEditingController _myController = new TextEditingController();
  String _result = "";
  String _inputList = "";

  setSum() {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < _myList.length; i++) {
      sum += _myList[i];
      if (i == 0)
        _inputList = "${_myList[i]}";
      else
        _inputList = _inputList + " + ${_myList[i]}";
    }
    _result = "$sum";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Demo App"),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
            child: new Text(
              _inputList,
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
            child: new Text(
              _result,
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 70.0),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0),
            child: new TextField(
              controller: _myController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onSubmitted: (text) {
                setState(() {
                  _myList.add(int.parse(text));
                  setSum();
                  _myController.clear();
                });
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like ...

```
import 'dart:core';

List<int> BuildIntArray(String input) {
  var outList = new List<int>();
  final _delimiter = ',';
  final _values = input.split(_delimiter);
  _values.forEach((item) {
    outList.add(int.parse(item));
    });
  return outList;
}
```

Which would ...

```
import 'package:IntegerArray/IntegerArray.dart' as IntegerArray;

main(List<String> arguments) {

  final input = "1,2,3,4,5";
  final intInputValues = IntegerArray.BuildIntArray(input);
  print (intInputValues);

  int sum = 0;
  intInputValues.forEach((item) {
    sum+=item;
  });

  print (sum);

}
```

... do this ...

```
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:64499/

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
15

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't see a "tryParse" to filter out non-numeric values ... but with some validation/error checking you could add to this ...